# Setting up a Buildbot hosting service for multiple projects

Tags: continuous-integration, hosting, buildbot, new-project

I need to set up a buildbot hosting environment which is capable of managing a large number of ***independent*** projects, and ideally provides a web front-end for users to manage their buildbot instance.

As far as I can gather, there isn't such a utility available at the moment.

I'm planning to roll my own, but could really use some advice before taking on this <strike>foolhardy</strike> task.

- Is such a project already available, or is there something similar I could build upon?
- Extend buildbot to allow build masters to manage multiple independent projects, or create a new utility to manage multiple instances of build masters?
- Anyone interested in collaborating on such an undertaking?

Any other advice to steer me down the right path also appreciated.

> **Some background info:**
>
> I'm trying to promote the use of
>   buildbot within my community but one
>   of the largest hurdle I face is how
>   complex the setup can be especially
>   for the uninitiated. 
>   *N.B. I work in a research environment where Fortran is (and has been for
>   decades) the language of choice and
>   Python is still somewhat novel.*
>
> It looks like the only way I can
>   promote widespread adoption of
>   buildbot across the many projects
>   within my community is to provide a
>   easy-to-use hosting service for buildbot.

Answer (score 2):

Previously, [Loki](http://fedorahosted.org/loki) was a  Django-based project used "to centralize the maintenance of buildbots across a large build farm."

Doesn't seem supported any longer, but the community does need something similar.

Ask on the [buildbot maillist](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/buildbot-devel). I think there was some other similar project underway as well, but I can't find the reference right now.

Comment: The previous incarnation (CLI) version doesn't really fit the bill but the new Django-based one sound like it may be heading the right direction. I'll have a peek. Thanks.

Comment: Loki is not supported at the moment :-(